# what was mac OS based on before UNIX?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Before macOS (I mean the Apple computers operating system before OSX) was Unix-Based, was there a terminal or command line application in it? And if so, what were the commands? What was it based on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's both too broad for the site's Q&A format, and not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: I am interested in the "command line" commands in early macOS versions

Comment: @IMSoP I find this practice of closing questions left and right somewhat arrogant and elitist. Maybe the question is too broad, or could be revised, but I think it sheds light on good information. Maybe rather than, 'What are the commands?' they might have asked 'What are the commands for x...y...z....?' I would say revising the question might be in order, but closing questions is lost learning opportunity.

Comment: @JozefPietrzak Once 5 users have voted to close a question, it is placed "On Hold", specifically to encourage the user to revise it. If it is not edited - as this one wasn't - it is eventually labelled as "closed", but is still visible, and still encourages users to improve it if possible. You seem to agree this question is too broad, so it seems harsh to call me "arrogant and elitist" for saying so; I left a custom note because I felt that just narrowing it down wouldn't make it on-topic, since it's more about OS design than programming. Feel free to raise a discussion on [meta].

Comment: @IMSoP Practices such as these are why I feel Stack is rapidly dying in favor of sites like Reddit. It is possible to get much more input there, which I have found in several cases ultimately leads to MANY more possible avenues for solutions or learning opportunities.

Comment: @IMSoP Many young people I work with and have mentored are very turned off and discouraged by common 'off-topic' deletions for what are in fact very niche or nuanced programming they are undertaking. It is also not helpful when someone shows up just to say things like 'read the basic PHP intro manual', contributing nothing of value and I suspect knowing full well the specific topic will not be even mentioned in the manual, let alone have it shed any meaningful light on the question at hand.

Comment: BTW I think the answer provided gave useful insight. Was it a programming question? I tend to think so, you can issue commands and do at least some rudimentary programming tasks from a terminal. The user may wish to know if it is even possible to interact with the OS on that level.

Comment: @JozefPietrzak I'm not sure why you're dredging this up after more than three years, but I stand by my earlier comments. It's an interesting topic for a discussion, but it doesn't fit the format and topic of this site; if that means the format of this site is less useful than the format of Reddit (which gets plenty of criticism itself) then so be it.

Comment: @IMSoP I’m at a loss. ‘So be it…’ So now I guess we don’t care if the platform is useful or not? Awesome, nope you’re right best just let it continue to devolve into a sad little place where those who know something already can flex how much they do know, but without actually helping or providing much to new generations. How superior indeed.

Comment: @JozefPietrzak What I meant was, there's no point turning this site into a poor clone of Reddit, if Reddit is already doing that job well. Either way, replying to one random user on a question they commented on 3 years ago isn't going to make any difference to how the site works, so I don't know what response you were expecting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was there a terminal or command line application in [Classic Mac OS]?

No, not really. Classic Mac OS was purely graphical; there was no underlying terminal. However, Apple provided two pieces of software for developers which could provide a *sort of* terminal:

The [MPW (Macintosh Programmer's Workshop)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) IDE, which was sold (and later offered as a free download) by Apple, had an unusual command-line interface. It had many commands which were analogous to standard UNIX utilities, and supported features like redirection and pipes. However, instead of operating in a terminal, it used an unusual interface where input and output was all part of a single text document (the "Worksheet"), and any line of the document could be executed using a particular keystroke.

The [MacsBug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacsBug) debugger, which was provided by Apple for free, also used a command-line interface. However, it was focused entirely on performing low-level debugging. It would never have been used for routine tasks.